# Does ambient pressure has an influence in the equilibrium contact angle of a sessile droplet (Laplace-Young Equation)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Does the equilibrium contact angle depend on the ambient pressure?

I understand that the Young-Dupre equation suggests the contact angle is independent of pressure, as it is determined by surface energies.

[image: Young-Dupre Eqn]

However, the Laplace-Young equation relates pressure and the droplet's curvature.

[image: Laplace-Young Eqn]

My understanding is that the equilibrium contact angle is determined by the surface energies as in Laplace-Dupre equation, and the Laplace-Young equation determines the pressure inside the sessile drop based on the ambient pressure outside. Based on this can we say that the equilibrium contact angle is independent of ambient pressure ( ignoring the relation b\w pressure and surface energies) ?

Comment: The gas composition and pressure certainly affect the surface tension; see, for example, Massoudi and King, "[Effect of pressure on the surface tension of water. Adsorption of low molecular weight gases on water at 25. deg"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100615a017).

Comment: Rephrased the question. My main intent was to know if pressure directly plays a role in influencing the contact angle ( ignoring the dependencies of surface tension and pressure)

Comment: no; it's the other way around - the contact angle influences the pressure difference P_in - P_out (but not the absolute values of pressure). For a droplet placed on a surface, the pressure difference in the Y-L eqn. is a function of the the contact angle.